# run javascript on debugger in chrome dev tools.

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I want to run on debugger my javascript code, 
make it pause in each step just like other backend languages can be debugged. 
I can't find the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

[DevTools snippets](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/authoring-development-workflow#snippets) may give you what you need. Just paste your code into a new snippet and you'll get all debugging support that you have for page scripts.